# Good quality data/packages for statistical/structure analysis of words in the English language

Tags: st.statistics, recreational-mathematics, cryptography

From time to time I find myself wishing to calculate basic statistics on words in the English language. For example, today I found myself wanting a graph of the number of English words vs. their length.

Admittedly, such queries usually arise for me in the context of conversational/recreational purposes, but with the obvious links to cryptography, computational game theory (Scrabble AI etc), and statistics, I think the following question easily falls within the purview of mathematical research.

**What good quality resources exist for performing statistical/structural analysis on the set of English words?**

One answer to this would be "get a decent word list and write an appropriate program", but, firstly, I don't know what the best word list is and where to get it , and, secondly,  in a post-Wolfram Alpha world, I am compelled to search for something higher level, that I can consult from time to time with little set-up needed. For example Mathematica seems to have an elaborate "WordData" package, though I am somewhat unsure of how exhaustive the data set is, given the following excerpt from the Wolfram site:

"Total number of words and phrases in WordData:
In[1]:= Length[WordData[All]]
Out[1]= 149191"

If anyone has first-hand experience with this package, or even better (as a Maple user), a similar or better resource that is standalone, (or implemented in Maple), then it would be great to hear about it.

Comment: I think that this is more of a programming question than a mathematical one and would be more appropriate on SO than MO.


Comment: I considered that too, but decided the kind of answers I want are more likely to be given by those doing mathematical research. I agree it is near the borderline, but I think I'm on the right side. The precedent of this question helped my decison: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19046/open-source-mathematical-software

Comment: I wasn't all that keen on that question, either!  I don't see any actual mathematics or application to mathematics in the question, though.  And the latter half is most definitely programming.

Comment: Actually, I'd say the latter half is mostly about avoiding programming. The mathematical focus of this question is the facilitation a mathematically informed understanding of the properties of the words in the English language, with very broad applicability to the areas of mathematics tagged.

Comment: Avoiding programming _is_ programming.  Your second sentence does not convince me that this particular question is sufficiently mathematical to be here.  What _mathematical_ research will be involved?  I can see that a linguist might use this in their research, but not a mathematician.

Comment: Well I've given my motivations, rationale, and well-defined question, but it seems like we might have different opinions on what a mathematician is allowed to do. So be it :) Please feel free to create and add the mathematical linguistics tag if you deem it appropriate!

Comment: It's not just about tagging.  I find it hard to figure out what would be a good answer to this question that is actually mathematical in content.  For example, the best answer to the example given (a graph of words by length) that I can think of is to send the dictionary that comes with a spell-checker program through a simple perl script.  No mathematics involved there at all.  As for "what a mathematician is allowed to do", not _everything_ a mathematician does is mathematics!

Comment: People who think of cryptography, computational game theory, statistics, recreational mathematics, or mathematical thinking in other fields as being mathematics could find the resource I ask about to be useful for doing research in those areas. The question has arisen for me, I think the question is okay here, and this is all I want to say about it. I am okay with the existence of differing opinions.

Comment: Definitely not an answer to your question, Q.Q.J., but if you do find some good software and get some good results, can you tell me whether you think George Kingsley Zipf was on the right track?  (Naive question, I suppose; but one finds all sorts of assertions on the internet and not a lot in which one feels inclined to repose great confidence.)

Comment: I'll keep it in mind Michael!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very sure this kind ofn things is done in the free (free  as in freedom, not as in beer!)
statistical language R.     ..    See www.r-project.org, and then repeat your question on 
the r-help mailing list, where you are sure to get informed answers about how to do it in R. 
That it can be done tere, and is done there, is a certainty.

( as for the meta-discussion where this belongs, it belongs on mathoverflow!  Statistics is math, not programming.)

Comment: The actual question asked is not statistics, though.

Answer (score 1):

The [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/book) for Python seems to pretty good.